# Cassandra UDT column as clustering column

Tags: java, database, cassandra, nosql, cassandra-3.0

I am using custom UDT type to store place information . It is stored as frozen blob/serialized type in table . For sorting based on country and state . **How much sense it make to keep UDT type as clustering column** . Will all serialized value of place having same country and state grouped together.

```
create type place(
    country Text,
    state Text
);

create table myTable(
    person Text,
    sale_place FROZEN<place>,
    sale_time TIMESTAMP,
    PRIMARY KEY( person,sale_place,sale_time)
) WITH CLUSTERING ORDER BY (sale_place ASC,sale_time ASC );
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I know, there isn't any restriction on using UDTs as part of primary key. Back in the initial days, the use of UDTs was discouraged inside primary key
(http://www.datastax.com/dev/blog/cql-in-2-1). The primary reason I believe was because UDTs at that time was mostly used for simplifying complex types within collections.

Nowadays, the pattern I believe is quite readable and should be fine to use in my opinion.